# Problem with Javascript localStorage for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, local-storage

I am using localStorage to store incoming message: `{"lastTid":22,"Hour":10,"min":31,"Second":34}` where the time is increasing in every new incoming object, e.g. next object: `{"lastTid":22,"Hour":10,"min":31,"Second":35}`.

The new messages are being stored in localStorage correctly as *seen* here:

[image]
[image]

My Javascript code implements the localStorage.getItem and .setItem correctly to retrieve and get my incoming data message, which will be rendered with `.innerHTML` to var `hst`, which `hst = document.getElementById("highscores")`. *all code below*

The ElementId "highscores" is assigned to `<table>` tag in my `html` and comes out as *seen* here: [image]

#js code snippet#

```
     var hst = document.getElementById("highscores");

     function onMessageArrived(message) {
        
        var data = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
        var highScores = [data];

        var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('highscores') || '[]');
        array.push(highScores);

        localStorage.setItem('highscores', JSON.stringify(array));
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        hst.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + array[i][0].Hour + ":"+ array[i][0].min + ":" + array[i][0].Second + "</td><td>" + array[i][0].lastTid + "</td></tr>";
        }
    };
```

My problem is, because of my For loop, when a new message arrives, my loop goes through and renders the previous message and the new message, while the old message is still in the table(**please see the table image above**). It is displaying object 0, object 0 & 1, then object 0, 1 & 2 all in the same table. Instead of 0, then 1 after, then 2 ... n.

I wish to display the values in proper order and also keep those values even after the page is reloaded. **Desired result:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this:
 for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
starting array from 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't append directly  `hst.innerHTML +=...`

try something like this

```
let html = ''
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + array[i][0].Hour + ":"+ array[i][0].min + ":" + array[i][0].Second + "</td><td>" + array[i][0].lastTid + "</td></tr>";
}
hst.innerHTML = html
```

Comment: Thank you this did the trick! Lastly, is there a way for the values to remain on the page after reloading the page? They return along with a new message, but disappear on page reload. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you doing this in vanilla JavaScript or a framework ? so I can give a better answer

Comment: No, I am simply writing in plain JS.

Comment: Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your always appending the array content at `hst.innerHTML` each incoming message, so the previous loop content remains. It's also not recommended for performance to manipulate DOM inside loops.

```
let res = '';
for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
  res += '<tr><td>' + array[i][0].Hour + ':' + array[i][0].min + ':' + array[i][0].Second + '</td><td>' + array[i][0].lastTid + '</td></tr>';
}
hst.innerHTML = res; // You overwrite the content instead of appending each time.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the same solution as the first one. Thank you. I wish to ask, is there a way for the values to remain on the page after reloading the page? They return along with a new message, but disappear on page reload. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you are rendering the values on then onMessageArrived event, you will need to move the rendering block to another function and call it from the load page event.

Comment: This method seemed to work. Thanks Tommy.